# Hstore index row size maximum error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore, postgresql-9.3

Using Rails 4 and trying to do an index on my hstore column.

My migration file:

```
class AddIndexToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "CREATE INDEX profiles_metadata_gin_data ON profiles USING GIN(meta_data)"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP INDEX profiles_metadata_gin_data"
  end
end
```

And the error I am receiving:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row size 7936 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "profiles_metadata_gin_data"
```

Any idea what to do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different index types have various restrictions on the size of items which may be indexed; in the case of your GIN index, it looks like you are well past the "GinMaxItemSize" limit, which is defined like so:

```
#define GinMaxItemSize \
    MAXALIGN_DOWN(((BLCKSZ - SizeOfPageHeaderData - \
            MAXALIGN(sizeof(GinPageOpaqueData))) / 3 - sizeof(ItemIdData)))
```

I think your workaround options are:

- Try a GIST index instead, I believe the limits there should be higher.
- Recompile Postgres with a larger block size, perhaps BLCKSZ=16384 would work.
- Use a partial GIN index skipping those troublesome large "meta_data" columns, e.g. `CREATE INDEX profiles_metadata_gin_data ON profiles USING GIN(meta_data) WHERE length(meta_data::text) < 2000`. You would have to include that same WHERE clause in queries in order for the index to get used though, which may be more trouble than it's worth.
- Find a way to trim the meta_data columns for those troublesome row(s) so that you can squeak under your 2712 byte limit for GIN.